# pull time error in git whil i am trying to get lastest code from git

Tags: java, git, liferay, bitbucket

when i am trying to get latest code from repository "git pull origin master" 
a message appear, 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    profile-summary-portlet/.project
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. 
I dont want it to merege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then make a `git reset --hard`
after that try to pull again.

your local data will be overwritten by this command! So be careful...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message says it all =). You can stash the changes and apply after if you do not want to merge now.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing